# Most performant way to group/summarise two hashes?

Tags: ruby

I have two hashes with some data that I need to aggregate. The first one is a mapping of which ids (id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4) belong under what category (a, b, c):

```
hash_1 = {'a' => ['id_1','id_2'], 'b' => ['id_3'], 'c' => ['id_4']}
```

The second hash holds values of how many events happened per id for a given date (date_1, date_2, date_3):

```
hash_2 = {
  'id_1' => {'date_1' => 5, 'date_2' => 6, 'date_3' => 8}, 
  'id_2' => {'date_1' => 0, 'date_3' => 6}, 
  'id_3' => {'date_1' => 0, 'date_2' => nil, 'date_3' => 1}, 
  'id_4' => {'date_1' => 10, 'date_2' => 1}
}
```

What I want is to get the total event per category (a,b,c). For the above example, the result would look something like:

```
hash_3 = {'a' => (5+6+8+0+6), 'b' => (0+0+1), 'c' => (10+1)}
```

My problem is, that there are about 5000 categories, each pointing to typically 1 to 3 ids, and each ID having event counts for 30 dates or more. So this takes quite a bit of computation. What will be the most performant (time effective) way to do this grouping in Ruby?

**update**
This is what I tried so far (took like 6-8 seconds!, horribly slow):

```
def total_clicks_per_category
  {}.tap do |res|
    hash_1.each do |cat, ids|
      res[cat] = total_event_per_ids(ids)
    end
  end
end

def total_event_per_ids(ids)
  ids.reduce(0) do |memo, id|
    events = hash_2.fetch(id, {})
    memo + (events.values.reduce(:+) || 0)
  end
end
```

P.S. I’m using Ruby 2.3.

Comment: Don’t be afraid to try something because there are 450,000 counts, either; that’s not actually very much. You’ll probably be surprised at how fast your solution works. (And if not, we’ll be here to help optimize it!)

Comment: see update abve

Comment: In your actual application do you know the approximate size of the array `hash_1.values.uniq`?

Comment: Yes around 5000-10000 For the most categories, only one ID corresponds. For a few categories 2-3 ID's corresponds.

Comment: With those numbers I don't see a more efficient approach than those contained in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm writing this on a phone so I cannot test right now, but it looks OK.

```
g = hash_2.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k] = v.values.compact.sum }
hash_3 = hash_1.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = g.values_at(*v).sum }
```

Comment: It would be okay with Ruby 2.4, OP uses Ruby 2.3

Comment: For Ruby versions prior to 2.4 (unless also using Rails, which has had `sum` for some time), replace `sum` with `reduce(:+)`.

Comment: Note that the OP also updated his input data. Values can be `nil` now.

Comment: @Eric, thanks. I had just noticed. When I saw I had another comment I knew what it was about and who it was from. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Theory

`5000*3*30` isn't that many. Ruby probably will need a second at most for this kind of job.

Hash lookup is fast by default, you won't be able to optimize much.

You could pre-calculate `hash_2_sum`, though :

```
hash_2_sum = {
  'id_1' => 5+6+8, 
  'id_2' => 0+6, 
  'id_3' => 0+0+1, 
  'id_4' => 10+1
}
```

A loop on `hash1` with `hash_2_sum` lookup, and you're done.

## Code

Your example has been updated with some `nil` values. You need to remove them with [`compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact), and make sure the sum is `0` when no element is found with [`inject(0, :+)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
hash_1 =  {'a' => ['id_1','id_2'], 'b' => ['id_3'], 'c' => ['id_4']}
hash_2 = {
  'id_1' => { 'date_1' => 5, 'date_2' => 6, 'date_3' => 8 },
  'id_2' => { 'date_1' => 0, 'date_3' => 6 },
  'id_3' => { 'date_1' => 0, 'date_2' => nil, 'date_3' => 1 },
  'id_4' => { 'date_1' => 10, 'date_2' => 1 }
}

hash_2_sum = hash_2.each_with_object({}) do |(key, dates), sum|
  sum[key] = dates.values.compact.inject(0, :+)
end

hash_3 = hash_1.each_with_object({}) do |(key, ids), sum|
  sum[key] = hash_2_sum.values_at(*ids).inject(0, :+)
end
# {"a"=>25, "b"=>1, "c"=>11}
```

## Note

```
 {}.tap do |res|
    hash_1.each do |cat, ids|
      res[cat] = total_event_per_ids(ids)
    end
  end
```

isn't very readable IMHO.

You can either use `each_with_object` or `Array#to_h` :

```
result = [1, 2, 3].each_with_object({}) do |i, hash|
  hash[i] = i * i
end
#=> {1=>1, 2=>4, 3=>9}

result = [1, 2, 3].map { |i| [i, i * i] }.to_h
#=> {1=>1, 2=>4, 3=>9}
```

Comment: Not just `inject(:+)`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland:  `[].inject(:+) #=> nil`, `[].inject(0,:+) #=> 0`

Answer (score 3):

First, create an intermediate hash that holds the sum of `hash_2`:

```
hash_4 = hash_2.map{|k, v| [k, v.values.inject(:+)]}.to_h
# => {"id_1"=>19, "id_2"=>6, "id_3"=>1, "id_4"=>11}
```

Then do the final summation:

```
hash_3 = hash_1.map{|k, v| [k, v.map{|k| hash_4[k]}.inject(:+)]}.to_h
# => {"a"=>25, "b"=>1, "c"=>11}
```